# Problem with x64 application and ActiveX control

Tags: c++, 64-bit, activex, unmanaged

I have a small unmanaged c++ application, I'm trying to use CoCreateInstance(...) to create an instance of the "Adobe SVG PLayer" which is installed as an ActiveX control.

When I compile and run my application under 32-bit configuration, it works fine, but when I compile under 64-bit configuration, my application fails to create the instance of the Adove SVG Player, although I know it is installed.

This is the code that I'm using for doing this:

```
const CLSID CLSID_SVGCtl = 
{0x377b5106,0x3b4e,0x4a2d,{0x85,0x20,0x87,0x67,0x59,0x0c,0xac,0x86}};

BOOL CheckSVGPresented()
{
    BOOL bResult = FALSE;
    try
    {
        IUnknown* pSvgCtrl = NULL;
        if (FAILED(::CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SVGCtl, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IUnknown, (LPVOID*)&pSvgCtrl)) || (NULL == pSvgCtrl))
            throw 1;
        bResult = TRUE;
        pSvgCtrl->Release();

    }
    catch (...)
    {       
        bResult = FALSE;
    }
    return bResult;
}
```

My guess is that probably I have an issue because I have a 64 bits host (my application) trying to create a 32-bits instance of an ActiveX dll (The SVG player).

I'm testing on Windows 7, x64 bits version.

So if you have any clue about this I will appreciate the help.

Comment: Did you recompile for the 64 bit version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that the ActiveX DLL you are trying to load is 32-bit only. Since ActiveX components are typically InProc, and 64 bit apps can't load in 32 bit DLLs, then you are correct about your guess.

http://thermous.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!8DC85127F8CE2F12!161.entry

Comment: too bad, that link is gone.  But answer is correct, 64-bit process cannot load any form of 32-bit native code.  Or vice-versa.  Application compiled to 64-bit can only use ActiveX that is also 64-bit.